# How to SSH to a specific computer behind a switch?

Tags: switch, service

I find it very hard to understand what exactly a switch* does (maybe because it does so little...).

Let's imagine that I have 3 computers connected through an unmanaged switch: `A`, `B` and `C`.

I am using computer `A`, how can I access the `SSH` server I have on `B`? What happens if both `B` and `C` are listening to port 22 at the same time?

*: I am talking about *switch* as in *(more elaborated) switching hub*, **not** as in *router*.

Comment: BE77Y's answer is good. There's no such thing as "behind a switch", since you've excluded routers (which would include L3 switches).

Answer (score 1):

As for what a network switch does - something like [this article](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/lan-switch.htm) should suffice (from a quick web search).

The long and short of it is that it simply acts as the physical medium between various network devices. It *switches* packets which are sent to it - inbound traffic sent to it on one port is sent on to its other ports so that connected devices can talk to one another.

It doesn't route packets - that is to say, if you're trying to get traffic from one IP subnet to another, it doesn't know how to do that - that's what routers are for.

As for your hypothetical - it doesn't matter if computer `B` and `C` are both listening on port 22 at the same time, because to be usable on the network they would both need unique IP addresses anyway.

Computer `A` would connect to either `B` or `C` via their IP address, on port 22.

That said, these questions are fairly basic in terms of network technology - I would recommend doing (quite a lot of) reading on the topic at large.

Comment: The article you cite, unless I have missed something, is as uninformative as almost everything I have found (clearly no offense intended, I am talking about the marketing crap I keep finding, not about your helpful answer). See: "how does a switch work? they connect multiple PC", "unmanaged? work out of the box", "managed? remote monitoring", "Switch vs. hub? Bandwidth problems"... Not only these article are uninformative, they are misleading too...

Comment: I do appreciate what you're getting at - it's jargon, rather than something helpful. Hopefully my brief explanation pointed you in the right direction, but I've just updated the link to something a lot more in-depth if you want to read about it in detail.

Comment: Regarding your answer, apparently switches are working at layer 2: they have no notion of IP address, only MACs... But anyway, let say `A` has a `DHCP` server running, how can `B` and `C` connect to `A` and get IPs (this is the same question as with SSH, only the other way around)?

Comment: To answer that you need a lot more information - I would read on the topic at large as per my answer, starting with the article I've now included.

Comment: http://www.dummies.com/programming/networking/cisco/network-basics-switching-and-the-osi-model/

Comment: @James - this site is not intended to be a back-and-forth conversation. "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." https://serverfault.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: The Wikipedia article on switches is also really good, for your further reading. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch